# Weinre - Not able to detect my mobile in Target

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, weinre

I'm trying to run weinre on my laptop IP (Say 130.x.x.x) and both the mobile and laptop are in the same WiFi network. I have added the script file URL in the index.html of my ionic project. When i try to open the weinre or target-script-min.js file on my mobile browser(chrome app), I'm able to view the same (No issues with firewall). However, if I try to run my application, I get

> "Failed to load resource:
>   http://130.x.x.x:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous 
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

I have googled around and found problems related to **cordova-whitelist** plugin. I have verified and by default I have allowed all IP

```
<content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://130.x.x.x/*" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
```

I still cant find the exact reason why I'm not able to download the .js in my app. Any idea on what could be wrong.

Comment: you should consider adding ur ipaddress in your content security policy

Comment: If it ends up being security issues related to using an ip address, you could try using a hostname from http://xip.io/ instead, which would end up mapping to your ip address.

Comment: @AbuHurairaLakdawala : tried giving my IP, still it didnt work.